# Jupyter-lab: The 'min_open_files_limit' trait of a ServerApp instance expected an int, not the NoneType None

Tags: jupyter-lab, anaconda3

I installed jupyter notebook using: **pip install jupyterlab** and tried to run it using : **jupyter-lab** but I'm jupyter lab is not getting launched.

Command prompt is getting stuck after the following output:

> [I 2021-09-21 00:20:30.717 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.

> [W 2021-09-21 00:20:30.749 ServerApp] The 'min_open_files_limit' trait of a ServerApp instance expected an int, not the NoneType None.

Answer (score 0):

This warning was fixed in `jupyter_server` [v1.11.1](https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter_server/releases/tag/v1.11.1) by [#587](https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter_server/pull/587). Please upgrade `jupyter_server` to get the fix:

```
# if you use pip:
pip install -U "jupyter_server>=1.11.1"
# or, if you use conda:
conda install -c conda-forge "jupyter_server>=1.11.1"
```